# RTnet vs CORBA transport

Tags: real-time

What is the difference between this two. And which should i choose for hard real time control purpose? What are the cons and pros of them one to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTnet and its transport protocol is described at http://www.rtnet.org/. "Hard Real-Time Networking for Real-Time Linux" (That network and web site use one of the numerous imprecise and conflicting "definitions" of the term "hard real-time.")

There are a great many descriptions of the ISO Real-Time CORBA standard on the web (Google). One major difference between RTNet and RTCORBA is that RTCORBA is intended for a wide variety of hard, soft, and non real-time distributed systems. The specification (more carefully) describes what meanings it uses for those terms. To accomplish that range of applicability--and specifically in regard to your question--the RTCORBA spec (not necessarily all vendor implementations) allows for application-specific pluggable transport protocols. Real-time and embedded CORBA products exist which are functionally and performance competitive with RTNet.

Which of the two depends on your application. CORBA in general is much more versatile than you need, unless you want to use a very special application-specific (for example, military aircraft) transport protocol which might not be accommodated by RTNet but which would be accommodated by certain RTCORBA implementations. A detailed answer to your question would require a lot of information about your needs and would probably be a very lengthy answer. Start by reading the web documents, being sure you know exactly what network capabilities you need.